# Experiencing out of bounds exception error with array list in Java

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception, bubble-sort

I'm trying to create a bubble swap method for arraylists in Java, but I've run into an error.
Here's my code:

```
public static void BubbleSort()
{
    list.remove("");
    for (int i = list.size(); i > 0; i--)
    {
        for (int j=0; j < i; j++)
        {
            if(Integer.valueOf((String) list.get(j)) < Integer.valueOf((String) list.get(j + 1)))
                Swap(list.get(j), list.get(j + 1));
        }
    }
    System.out.println(list);
}
```

And here's the Swap method it calls:

```
public static void Swap(Object object, Object object2)
{
    Object spotC = object; 
    list.set(list.indexOf(object), object2); 
    list.set(list.indexOf(object2), spotC);
}
```

Comment: Make the debugger your best friend.

Comment: What's the stack trace?

Comment: It's getting suspended at the if statement within the second for loop

Comment: Post the whole class. What is `list`? Look up how to use `list.remove()`. I do not think it works exactly how you think it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
public static void BubbleSort()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
    {
        for (int j=i+1; j < list.size(); j++)
        {
            if(Integer.valueOf(list.get(i).toString()) > Integer.valueOf(list.get(j).toString()))
                Swap(list.get(j), list.get(i));
        }
    }
    System.out.println(list);
}


public static void Swap(Object object, Object object2)
{
    Object spotC = object; 
    list.set(list.indexOf(object), object2); 
    list.set(list.indexOf(object2), spotC);
}
```

Comment: It worked perfectly. I see now that the error was caused by my original for loop counting down while the nested for loop was initialized at zero, causing small conflicts between the two. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 6):

The exception may occur when`i` is `list.size()`, so in then nested `for` loop, when `j` takes its last value `i - 1` that is equal to `list.size() - 1`, `Swap` is called with the elements

```
list.get(j), list.get(j + 1)
```

in other words

```
list.get(list.size() - 1), list.get(list.size())
```

But you cannot access to `list.get(list.size())` since the index is not valid. Remember indexes start with `0` and ends with `length - 1`.

Comment: I changed int i = list.size() to int i = list.size() - 1. It fixed the error, but now it appears that my sorting isn't working at all. I'm displaying the apparently modified arraylist, but it's coming back as the exact same numbers. Any suggestions?